# Is it possible to use iOS7's AirDrop with the Mac AirDrop?

Tags: ios, airdrop

iOS 7 is out, and it has AirDrop. I'd like to be able to AirDrop files between my Mac and my iPhone, but it seems that iOS devices don't show up on the Mac AirDrop console.

Is it possible to use AirDrop to transfer files between a Mac and an iOS7 device? Is there, say, a file-manager app I can install that makes it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not Yet, I have tested it and TechHive [confirms](http://www.techhive.com/article/2048903/how-to-share-files-on-ios-7-using-airdrop.html). Though Mavericks **may** bring this functionality (complete speculation obviously).

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for either of those claims?

Comment: The first is from experience. I've tried it and it doesn't work. If you think techhive.com is authoritative they also confirm http://www.techhive.com/article/2048903/how-to-share-files-on-ios-7-using-airdrop.html

Comment: @nneonneo The second is speculation with the key word being 'may'.

Comment: @SteveMoser I would suggest you expand your answer with those facts.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's it then. Here's to hoping the feature does make it in to 10.9.

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 Yosemite, you **can** share files over AirDrop between Mac and iOS.

[image]

<sup>Image source: http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/02/finally-airdrop-works-between-ios-and-mac/</sup>