# How can I send/receive files from my iPhone over Bluetooth to my Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

Why is it so difficult to Bluetooth these two?  They are both Apple products and it seems inconceivable that it won't work.  I have tried several solutions posted online and can link but there is no data flow between them. Anyone solved this?

MacBook Pro with Mavericks & iPhone 4s

Comment: What is the exact problem you are encountering? Without more information, getting a proper answer is virtually impossible.

Comment: thnx Lance.  The 2 have paired on the surface of it but no file transfers are possible .  The error is 'does not have the necessary services'.  My old Sony could do this so why not an Apple product?  I simply want to send a file from mac to iphone

Answer (score 5):

iPhone does not support Bluetooth File Exchange.

Comment: Furthermore, [AirDrop interoperability is scheduled as a new feature for OS X Yosemite](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/133212/21748).

Answer (score 1):

You could connect together using WiFi rather than Bluetooth by creating an ad-hoc network on you MacBook Pro

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/09/25/mac-101-create-a-wireless-network-between-mac-and-iphone/

Then use an app like Feem to transfer the files

http://www.tryfeem.com

I agree that Bluetooth solution should be available.